# Database size for news publishers?

Tags: database

My site is focused on gaming news and tips & tricks. Recently I had an issue where my hosting provider told me my site was using a lot of resources on the shared server. After a database cleanup everything is fine, but I am a bit worried how much time will it take until I have to move to a bigger hosting solution.

1. How do big news website deal with this?
2. Is there a way to have multiple small databases to load my wordpress content?

Thanks!

Comment: You actually didn't provide any useful fact on what your problem was. What resources are you referring? Do you mean the database the CPU Multiple concurrent users? Do you use CDN? Database clean up? Your questions are a little bit too general as for how do you define `big news websites`

Comment: Hey Jack! Sorry for not being that specific on the data: 
What resources are you referring? They said I was using more resources of the server that I was supposed to.
Do you use a CDN? Just got one a day ago.
Database Cleanup? I was told that I needed to optimize my database.
Big news website? I meant sites like Buzzfeed, Gizmodo, Mashable, etc. The volume of posts published a day is huge, so I suppose they have immense database size. Are there multiple databases? Is it only 1 ultra big one?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely not the size itself but how queries are being done. This could be a result of non optimal code or bad DB structure.

As with all optimization you first need to find the actual bottle necks and than to decide if you fix the code, or maybe just scrap the feature.

In any case, if you care about performance or avoiding artificial limitations, you should not be hosting on a shared host but use a VPS instead.